# Show a cell.button only if file exists

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfilemanager

I have a table view with some cells populated by 2 labels.
If an mp3 file named "label1-label2-name" exists, I play the file.

```
 NSArray *final;
 NSString *element;
 final = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", nil];
```

Now in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I'm trying to do the same, but just to show the play button if the file exists (button is initially hidden).

```
- (CustomCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 for (element in final) {

    buttonA = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-AAA-%@", current[indexPath.row][0],current[indexPath.row][1], element];
    fileA = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:buttonA ofType:@"mp3"];
    BOOL fileExistsA = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileA];

    if (fileExistsA) {

        cell.playA.hidden = false;

    }
 }
}
```

What's happening here is that even if a file named "label1-label-2-AAA-a" exists, if the file "label1-label-2-AAA-d" doesn't, the play button will be hidden.

**How to show/hide the play at specific cells?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from the code snippet you've shared if you are reusing cells or not, but assuming you are, you may want to update the `cell.playA.hidden` state in both cases (e.g. if the file exists or not), otherwise you won't see the "play" button once a cell with a existent mp3 file appears on screen, and, while configuring it, you dequeue a cell with a previously hidden button.

```
- (CustomCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    /// Get the cell

    cell.playA.hidden = true;
    for (element in final) {
        buttonA = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-AAA-%@", current[indexPath.row][0],current[indexPath.row][1], element];
        fileA = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:buttonA ofType:@"mp3"];
        BOOL fileExistsA = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileA];
        if (fileExistsA) {
            cell.playA.hidden = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming it is what you want, we check all possible filenames for this cell (*"label1-label-2-AAA-**a**"*, *"label1-label-2-AAA-**b**"*, ...), and if *at least one* is present, we show the button, otherwise we hide it.

Comment: so like this? `cell.playA.hidden = !fileExistsA;` and then `for (element in final) {

    buttonA = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-AAA-%@", current[indexPath.row][0],current[indexPath.row][1], element];
    fileA = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:buttonA ofType:@"mp3"];
    BOOL fileExistsA = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileA]; }`

Comment: Sorry I've misread your question — I didn't realise you cycle through `final` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @rmaddy No it won't, I kept cell reusing in mind. Please, follow through the method again: code in the initial question cycles through an array to find at least one existing file. So I reset the `hidden` property first, and then set it to `true` if we find at least one.

Comment: @AlexStaravoitau Oops. I did overlook that first line. Sorry about that.